# イメージボタン押下をPHP側で検知して、セッションをクリアしたい

Tags: php, html

標題の件、超初心者らしい問い合わせですが　何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。

セッションクリアが目的なので、PHP側で押下を検知できる性質の要素（ボタン）で、ボタン画像は当方が用意するものに差し替えたい条件があります。

このことからしてHTML上　このボタンはinput要素でtype="image"（type="submit"ではなく）である必要があると解釈しました。button要素でもない認識をしています。

＝＝＝質問＝＝＝
以下HTMLのなかのinput type="image" name="logoffbtn"が目的を達成するうえで今回用意した要素ですが、押下しても無反応になってしまいます。押下してもチラツキもしません（送信されている気配なし）
PHP側で押下を認識できない原因は何ですか？
input type="image"は初めて使った要素ですが、そもそも要素の選択から誤っているのでしょうか？（正しい選択？？）

```
<h1>
    <div style="text-align:right; color:#FF0000; font-size:large" >
        <span id="msg"></span>
        <a href="menu.php"><img src="img/btn_tomenu_ontop.png" alt=""></a>
        <input type="image" name="logoffbtn" src="img/btn_logoff_ontop.png" />
    </div>
</h1>



<?php 
    if (isset($_POST["logoffbtn"])){
        session_destroy();
        header("location: logon.php");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INPUTタグをFORMタグで囲ってみてください。
例えば以下のようにします。

```
<h1>
    <div style="text-align:right; color:#FF0000; font-size:large" >
    <form action="menu.php" method="POST">
            <span id="msg"></span>
            <a href="menu.php"><img src="img/btn_tomenu_ontop.png" alt=""></a>
            <input type="image" name="logoffbtn" src="img/btn_logoff_ontop.png" />
    </form>
    </div>
</h1>
```

Comment: 思い出しました、感じなことを。そうでしたそうでした、ありがとうございます。